# s3Zip getting error - cannot read property of null

Tags: amazon-s3, zip

I have an expressjs back end and I'm trying to download/stream pdfs from s3 to a zip file. This is the error in the Heroku log: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null
    at Object.s3Zip.archiveStream (/app/node_modules/s3-zip/s3-zip.js:49:6)
    at Object.s3Zip.archive (/app/node_modules/s3-zip/s3-zip.js:33:24)

It was working on a localhost with "s3-zip": "^2.0.4" however I never deployed that version to heroku. Now I'm using "s3-zip": "^3.1.2"

also note, in my IDE the .archive statement is crossed out with a hint comment that a: Depreciated symbol used

```
public getZipFiles(req, res) {

    const get_file = req.headers['pdfs'].split(',');
    console.log("get file: ", get_file);
    // first param is the zip file name
    const zip_file_name = get_file.shift() + '.zip';


    const user_downloads = downloadsFolder();

    console.log(downloadsFolder()); // value is /tmp/
    const output = fs.createWriteStream(join(user_downloads, zip_file_name));
    // note: get_file is an array - ['file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf']
    s3Zip
        .archive({ region: aws_region, bucket: aws_bucket, debug: true }, '', get_file)
        .pipe(output)

};
```

I expected to see the downloaded zip file, but got the error instead

Comment: [Girum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7234281/girum) [asks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58826374/3744182), *Did you find a solution to this problem? or figure out what was the cause of it?*